# Comic from an old newspaper about a girl running through a winter forest and collapsing, with the story "continuing"

Tags: identification-request, comics

I'm trying to find a comic that I saw in a newspaper in 2014 or thereabouts (I think it was Atlanta Journal-Constitution, but not sure). I don't remember the issue number, when exactly I saw it, or any other stories in the paper. It looked like a regular, wide-circulation paper (I don't think it was a special issue)

I tried looking up "AJC comics" and finding old issues of the paper, but nothing came up.

The images were in color and drawn sort of realistically (not "cartoony"), but not lifelike; I think I remember them being kind of angular-looking. There was no dialogue or captions at all.

It had something to do with a girl running through a forest in the winter (there was snow on the ground). I don't remember exactly but she might have been wearing a yellow coat. It isn't clear what she's running from or to. There's about 5 frames of that until she collapses from the cold.

Just then someone is shown reaching out to help her stand up (only their arms are shown). Then the comic said something about the reader "continuing the story" on their own.

Comment: Hi Cor, welcome! Please check out our [tour] and [identification-request wiki](/tags/identification-request/info). If anything from the latter jogs your memory, please [edit] your question with more details. For example, what was the art style? If not the Journal-Constitution, what are some possibilities? Was this from a regular strip, and would it have been something with wide circulation? How the issue in general - any details about other comics, or the stories covered in that day's paper. Would this have been a Sunday paper or are you not sure on the day of the week? Every detail may help!

Comment: @bobble  Thanks! I added some more specifics.